# Could not retrieve schema information for table or view [database table name]

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm creating a project and want to connect it to database. I clicked add new data source in the data menu above. When i clicked finish, the error poped up. This is the error:

"could not retrieve schema information for table or view ...DatabaseName"

[image]

Comment: Could be a connection problem to the database or the table does not exist (check the owner id and your spelling), or even a privileges problem.

Comment: What could be the possible problem? The table does exist. Help please.

Comment: Can you access any table you have created? If the answer is no, chances are it is a connection string problem. Either a network issue or the string used to connect with is wrong or the userid password is wrong,...etc. If you can access some tables other than this one, then try to qualify the name of the table to look like: dbo.tablename instead of just tablename. It helps to add the type of database in your question tag as well.

Comment: What kind of DataSource have you added? SQL Server, SQL Server CE or LocalDB?

Comment: @LocEngineer LocalDB. Microsoft Access Database File.

Comment: @NoChance Strangely, all of my other database files is having the error like that. I created my last project 5months ago.

Comment: What now? LocalDB with file extension `.mdf`or Access Database file `.accdb`?

Comment: @LocEngineer Sorry. It's Access Database file .accdb

Comment: Hmmm.. cannot reproduce. Can you open your database correctly in Access? Why is it asking for a schema? There is no schema with Access databases, AFAIK.

Comment: See the connection string here:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73bcc81c-83ad-4d3a-85db-89ac51ce35eb/could-not-retrieve-schema-information-for-table-or-view-databasename?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Yes i can open it correctly.

Comment: I have the same connection string, but doesnt work either.

Comment: I have found an interesting comment by user CaptainDash here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73bcc81c-83ad-4d3a-85db-89ac51ce35eb/could-not-retrieve-schema-information-for-table-or-view-databasename?forum=vbgeneral `I was missing an SQL dll.  I had uninstalled SqlServer 2008 and was going to install the new 2012.  In the interim, between the uninstall and re-install I ran into the issue as noted above.  I'm guessing that the uninstall process removed some necessary files.` Does that shed light on the issue?

Comment: I will try this one, thanks.

Comment: Somewhat related issue: When trying to add a table to the DBML designer, I got the error “Could not retrieve schema information for database object <object name>”. I tried refreshing the DB connection—that didn’t work. What worked was closing Visual Studio and opening it again. Hope this helps someone..

Comment: I faced the same issue and after a lot of trying, i solved it see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589648/could-not-retrieve-schema-information-for-table-or-view-error-in-vs-2017-m-a).